# Netty local filechannel implementation

Tags: java, netty, codec, channel

I'm working on a project where we need to encode/decode files locally. Our team decided to use netty because the project may be extended to send/receive data via sockets and handlers are easy to use (writing one handler per codec looked like a good idea). For now the the idea is to read/write files locally. But I couldn't find any channel implementation which would work on files instead of sockets. Is there any channel for this job or should I just implement it myself?

The closest channel I could use was localchannel but that wouldn't work because it uses queue and writes directly to peer's queue (even thought there are no sockets, this class works locally and just simulates how sockets would work).

I'd like to know if there is an implementation of this kind of channel for netty. Or some pointers about how it can be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like this included in netty and so you would need to implement it by yourself